# HDD in DVD drive caddy seems to fall asleep?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop

I just installed an HDD caddy in place of my laptop's optical disc drive and it has been working fine with transfer speeds, etc, but I have placed my source code projects into it and something strange was happening in Visual Studio Code. If I go for some lengths of time without saving to the hard drive, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, it will take a second or more for the file to save but after that, I can save quite fast for a while. Then when some time passes again before I save, it'll have that few second delay in saving again.

I can't quite pinpoint the interval how long between the saving issue happens, maybe a few minutes in-between?

I can't figure out how to resolve this issue because the HDD seems to function fine otherwise. I also play games that are stored in it so my conclusion is that since VS Code is installed on my main drive C: and only the source files are in the HDD in the caddy, it goes to sleep when no activity is detected.

**UPDATE:**
I have verified that it takes as little as 30 seconds after I didn't do anything with the drive for it to go to sleep. I think 30 seconds is a bit much.

Answer (score 3):

The OS may put the drive in standby / sleep mode to save power. In this low power mode the actuator is moved to the landing zone. The standby mode power consumption is <1W, whereas idle mode power consumption is around 3-5W. R/W mode consumption can go up to 8W<sup>1</sup>. The HDD may also spin down to reduce the noise.

The HDD powerdown time can be adjusted in Windows Power Settings. However that might not affect the external drive. One way to keep it spinning with OS tools is by repeatedly writing and deleting a zero-byte file to the drive in short enough intervals that it won't the drive can't spin down.

According to some sources<sup>2</sup> spinning disks down when not in use also reduces wear and tear. This is mostly debated in discussion forums, counterclaim being that spinup/down actually increases the wear and tear. I find no actual research into this, but the counterclaim is supported by the facts that a) datacenter/server disks do spin continuously and b) HDD manufacturers don't list spinup/down cycles anymore but only load/unload cycles.

---

<sup>1: [Seagate Barracuda](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/3-5-barracudaDS1900-11-1806US-en_US.pdf), [WD Red](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-red-hdd/product-brief-western-digital-wd-red-hdd.pdf) , [WD Blue](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-blue-hdd/product-brief-western-digital-wd-blue-pc-hdd.pdf)</sup>

<sup>2: [Toshiba Storage Solutions KB](https://www.toshiba-storage.com/es/trends-technology/mttf-what-hard-drive-reliability-really-means/), [Netgear ReadyNAS KB](https://kb.netgear.com/30903/How-do-I-enable-disk-spin-down-on-my-ReadyNAS), my own schooling from when home PCs weren't a thing;and 5.25" HDDs were just introduced, old geezers calling them Winchester drives...</sup>

Comment: But I was using this same hard drive on a desktop and it wasn't having this issue though? And it seems a bit too aggressive because not even 5 minutes has passed and the drive's already asleep

Comment: 5 minutes is anything but aggressive, IMO. I do see your point tho; even if it doesn't really take that long for the disks to spin up again, when you're in the flow that couple of extra seconds can be really disturbing as it breaks your rhythm. That's one of the reasons I changed to SSDs long ago, I only use HDDs for long-term, seldom-accessed storage.

Comment: @peregerino69 I just did a test and found out it was actually 30 seconds of inactivity before it goes to sleep

Comment: Also I might have accidentally edited your answer instead of my question, please disregard that edit

Comment: `HDDs are designed to go to standby mode` .. no, this is not absolute.  They are designed to spin forever.  The controller itself might be designed with this in mind (to save power) but the drives are not.  The spindown is because the controller told it to.  Many controllers do not do this.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Huh? That's what I was taught studying computer mechanics back when home PCs were new and upcoming  thing. Never double-checked, as my drives have always spun down... just a month ago shelved a couple of external HDDs, they did with Win but not with Debian; thunk them's break. Thanks. I'll leave this up nonetheless 'till I find some confirmation one way or another.

Comment: "so allowing them to spin continuously shortens their lifespan significantly"  [citation needed].  Apart from that, laptop HDDs probably do spin down to protect against accidents.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is perhaps because the disk is plugged-in to the DVD drive.
Your motherboard is perhaps treating it as a removable device,
thus putting it to sleep after a period of idle time.

When it was plugged-in to the other computer as an ordinary
internal disk, it was certainly not treated as removable.

When the disk is in the sleep state, any reference to it will wake
it up, but with a small delay when it happens.
If you can hear the disk, you may verify it by listening
carefully whenever you wake it up.

On my computer I can distinguish between a removable device
and an internal disk by in Disk Management right-clicking the disk,
and checking the "Policies" tab. See if it differs there from
the real internal disk(s). (*Edit: Didn't work for the poster.*)

Try using the open-source and free
[KeepAliveHD](https://github.com/stsrki/keepalivehd) :

> KeepAliveHD is a simple program which prevents your hard drive to go into automatic standby mode. It works by writing a small text file to your external drive every few minutes.

You may find more such programs
[here](https://alternativeto.net/software/keepalivehd/).

Comment: Is there a way, some registry tweak or something to make Windows _not_ do that?

Comment: Try in the "Policies" tab to set it to "Better performance". This might do it.

Comment: They have the exact same Policies tab with the same options checked (both main and optical drive HDD) "Enable write caching on the device"

Comment: The only option in the Policies tab for both is "Write caching policy"

Comment: I'll check it more tomorrow.

Comment: Alright, thank you in advance!

Comment: As @harrymc theorizes, this might be 100% caused by the controller (DVD/ATAPI).  I have had drives like this.  I have even written 5 line `c` services to "ping" the drive every 28 seconds and have the problem go away (both in Windows and Linux) with little to no performance degradation.  In my case, it was specifically external WD book drives.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas what method did you use to "ping" the drive? Did you constantly create and delete a blank file or something else?

Comment: @user9564371: (1) In *Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings*, under "Hard disk", is the “Turn off hard disk after” setting "Never"? If you can't see it, click “Change settings that are currently unavailable”. (2) In Device Manager, under which branch do you see your disk? Is it "Disk drives"? (3) I added the KeepAliveHD project to my answer.

Comment: @harrymc (1) I've already set that and it did not do anything, and besides, they were set to 10 minutes and 20 minutes respectively for battery and plugged in, but my drive sleeps after 30 seconds so it's gotta be something else. (2) My HDD in the caddy shows up under "Disk Drives" along with the main internal one. (3) I am aware of such programs, I could write a small script that does it but I was wondering if SeñorCMasMas had a different approach of poking the drive awake other than constantly writing a dud file to it 24/7

Comment: @user9564371: It's enough to ask for the disk's status to keep it alive, no writing is required. Perhaps one of the alternatives to KeepAliveHD in my last link does it this way.

Comment: @harrymc I used AHK to get the drive's free space at an interval of 15 seconds and it seemed to not do the trick, the only thing that really seemed to work is just writing a blank file over and over. And all of the alternatives in your link do the same thing

Comment: @user9564371: Perhaps indeed there is no other alternative.

Comment: no, I checked the root folder for existence using the [_access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/access-waccess?view=msvc-170) function.  Something like  `_access( "c:\", 0 );` .. in theroy, `_access( ".", 0 );` should be valid too but never tried it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: That's what I know - that any action on a drive counts as not being idle, so the idle counter restarts again. But the poster says this doesn't work. Strange.

Comment: Why would the AHCI controller or Windows even know that a specific SATA port is meant for a DVD drive?  I'd expect all of the internal SATA ports to behave the same.

Comment: @OskarSkog: Theorizing only: For example, if the disks were on SATA3 but the DVD was on SATA2.